# How to revert a virtual machine back to original state

Tags: virtualmachine

Is there any shortcut way where I can bring my virtual machine back to the new original state. I don’t want to create a new virtual machine, instead I want to revert my machine back to factory defaults. Basically I want to do this for my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing virtual machines not software QA and testing

Comment: Is this so that you can guarantee that your testing environment is always pristine?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you take a look at Vagrant - https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/. Tearing down a VM is as simple as running 'vagrant destroy' from the command line. When you're ready to bring it back up, you can re-provision with 'vagrant up'

Comment: +1 How could I forget about Vagrant, much better idea then snapshots for having a update/clean dev and test environments.

Answer (score 1):

Most virtualization software supports [snapshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29).

> A snapshot is the state of a system at a particular point in time.

The free/open-source [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) supports [snapshot creation and restoring from the command line](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20810). Also [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation) [supports snapshots from the commandline](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_learning_cli_vmrun.html) with the *revertToSnapshot* option.

This allows you to create a [batch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)/[shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) script which you could trigger/run to restore the VM to a certain point in time.

Keep in mind that a snapshotted machine will be somewhat slower since it has to keep track of all changes made to the disk.